# Error when running artisan migrate in dockerfile

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to build a docker image to a Laravel (3) application.
As part of the process I try to run migration in the dockerfile:

```
RUN php /api/artisan migrate:install --env=local
RUN php /api/artisan migrate --env=local
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /api/laravel/database/connectors/mysql.php on line 33
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>   PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /api/laravel/database/connectors/mysql.php on line 33

But! when I try to run the container I built, with the script 
`cd api && php artisan migrate:install --env=local && php artisan migrate --env=local && service apache2 start` - everything works as expected.

I have no idea what can lead to the error.
Any insights, please?

A different best practice for migrating a laravel app while using docker is also welcomed!

Comment: When you say "relies on the domain", what domain are you referring to? The hosts resolver domain?

Comment: Never mind, It's not the case, I explicitly give it `--env=local` :( editing my Q...